# iADs in cocos 2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, implementation, iad

Hello i'm new to cocos 2D and am thinking about implementing iADs in a new app i'm working on. I'v used iADs before and know the framework pretty well but i know that cocos 2D works in Layers and not views and am a little confused on how to implement them in my app. Can someone please walk me through just how to get them to show up i'm completely confused by other tutorials. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this tutorial?

- [Implementing iAd on Cocos2d Application](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/751_Implementing_iAd_on_Cocos2d_Application.aspx)

This tutorial is also helpful.

- [Integrate cocos2d and UIKit](http://bobueland.com/cocos2d/?p=259)